# urllib2.urlopen not getting all content

Tags: python, urllib2, python-requests

I am a beginner in python to pull some data from reddit.com
More precisely, I am trying to send a request to http:www.reddit.com/r/nba/.json to get the JSON content of the page and then parse it for entries about a specific team or player.

To automate the data gathering, I am requesting the page like this:

```
import urllib2
FH = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.reddit.com/r/nba/.json")
rnba = FH.readlines()
rnba = str(rnba[0]) 
FH.close()
```

I am also pulling the content like this on a copy of the script, just to be sure:

```
FH = requests.get("http://www.reddit.com/r/nba/.json",timeout=10)

rnba_json = FH.json()   
FH.close()
```

However, I am not getting the full data that is presented when I manually go to 
http://www.reddit.com/r/nba/.json with either method, in particular when I call

```
print len(rnba_json['data']['children']) # prints 20-something child stories
```

but when I do the same loading the copy-pasted JSON string like this:

```
import json
import urllib2
fh = r"""{"kind": "Listing", "data": {"modhash": ..."""# long JSON string 
r_nba = json.loads(fh)      #loads the json string from the site into json object
print len(r_nba['data']['children'])        #prints upwards of 100 stories
```

I get more story links. I know about the timeout parameter but providing it did not resolve anything.

What am I doing wrong or what can I do to get all the content presented when I pull the page in the browser?

Comment: I did it both way and got the same result for `len(j['data']['children])`: 25 stories

Comment: by 'both' ways do you mean with a python request vs. going to the website and copy pasting? If so, is your code different than mine?

Comment: Indeed, I even used wget and got the same result. My code was from the interpreter: `x=urllib2.urlopen(dir).read();j=json.loads(x);len(j['data']['children']) >> 25`

Comment: are you sure about that `rnba = str(rnba[0]) `? edit: just tested, it does return a single line

Comment: Well I don't know what to say, there are definitely more than 25 story links in the front page, and about 100 when I copy paste it (just like the regular www.reddit.com/r/nba 
Can you get all those 100 stories from  the front page?

Comment: Ok, just did some poking around (this is my first time playing with APIs) and found this from [link](http://www.reddit.com/dev/api/oauth#GET_r_{subreddit}_about.json)
and found this:
GET /subreddits/mine/where[ .json | .xml ]
limit 
the maximum number of items desired (default: 25, maximum: 100)

How can I use this to obtain all 100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the max allowed, you'd use the API like: http://www.reddit.com/r/nba/.json?limit=100

Comment: When you load this into a json object and get len(rnba_json['data']['children])
it still gives 25. I think the problem is that the reddit api limits non-browser requests to 25 by default, but I don't know how to get all 100.
 [link](http://www.reddit.com/dev/api/oauth#GET_r_{subreddit}_about.json) and found this: GET /subreddits/mine/where[ .json | .xml ] limit  the maximum number of items desired (default: 25, maximum: 100) How can I use this to obtain all 100?

Comment: THANK YOU! Yes, that did it! Is there anything I should do to mark this 'answered' or anything else to conform with the etiquette of the site?
Again, thanks!

Comment: I'll edit my answer to reflect what you wanted.  You click the checkmark next to the answer to mark it.